# Round off the decimal place of a number to the next multiple of 0.05

Tags: javascript

I want to Round off the decimal place of a number to the next multiple of 5
I have tried this but it's not working for decimal places

```
const roundOff = (num) =>{

 let temp = parseFloat(num.toFixed(2)) // to make it 2 place decimal
 return Math.ceil(temp / 5) * 5

  }

roundOff(54.5678)  // should give 54.60
roundOff(43.738)   // should give 43.75
roundOff(89.982)   // should give 90.00 
roundOff(80.034)   // should give 80.05
```

Comment: `Math.round(num * 2) / 2`

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks for the solution but its giving me the and with 1 decimal value only. I need in 2 decimals.

Comment: @geekglance The solution of @JonasWilms rounds to the closest multiple of 2. Just replace 2 by 100 to get "rounding to two digits". The solution is simply more flexible. Alternatively also `Math.round(num / prec) * prec` where `prec` denotes the step-side of the equidistant grid being rounded to.

Answer (score 14):

```js
const roundOff = (num) =>{
 return (Math.ceil(num * 20) / 20).toFixed(2)
}

console.log(roundOff(54.5678))  // should give 54.60
console.log(roundOff(43.738))   // should give 43.75
console.log(roundOff(89.982))   // should give 90.00 
console.log(roundOff(80.034))
```

Comment: Negative vote, because 1) it doe's not round to the the nearest multiple of 0.05 and 2) returns not a *rounded number*, but a string.

Comment: `roundOff(54.551)` returns the string "54.60"``, but should return number `54.55`.

Comment: @Wiimm, no, in the question it is stated that it should round to the `next multiple of 5` and also `roundOff(54.5678)  // should give 54.60` is virtually the same case

Comment: Ok, rounding direction is my failure, but the result is still a string. Negative vote removed.

Comment: @Vulwsztyn you are correct, but his posted code uses 0.05 (I just now corrected the title)

Comment: @Wiimm  No, the "next" (not "last") multiple [up] from 54.551 is indeed 54.60.

Comment: There are still some corner cases that are broken due to the way floats work, BTW.  As examples: 1.05000000000000004 and 1000000000000000.05.